# How can I store the data that populates a div upon an onClick event and then repopulates that div upon refresh?

Tags: javascript

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(event){
        var timeIn = (document.getElementById("timeIn").value);
        var timeOut = (document.getElementById("timeOut").value);
        var aDate = (document.getElementById("datepicker").value);
        $('#timeIn').val(' ');
        $('#timeOut').val(' ');
        $('#datepicker').val(' ');
        $('.daysContain').find('div').eq(inArray.length-1).append('Time In: ' + timeOut);
        $('.daysContain').find('div').eq(outArray.length-1).append('Time Out: ' + timeIn);
        $('.daysContain').find('div').eq(weekArray.length-1).prepend(aDate);

});
```

Im in the process of creating an inner office 'Project-Time' application that will allow employees a way of inputting time spent on a project. The above js function works but now I need a way to retain the data after a refresh. Im not looking for exacts I simply need a push in the right direction (this is the first time I've had to deal with this hurdle). Any *good* suggestions are welcome-

Comment: There are many ways to store the data. Most of them will involve persisting data to your server.

Comment: @Shmiddty would it be possible to output to XML doc for storing on server & then repopulate those divs from that XML doc?

Comment: Yes. I'd suggest using google to find a method to accomplish this with the server technology you are using.